# Geometry optimization using DFT

Tags: density-functional-theory, band-structure, geometry-optimization, siesta

I have been attempting to optimize the structure of a Si nanowire using SIESTA. The original structure fed into the optimization is as follows.

[image: Original structure]

Once it is optimized, the structure would change to being as given below.
[image: Optimized structure]

In this, there appears to be several atoms moving away from cubic diamond lattice structure (white atoms) as the structure gets optimized (which is something that I expected). However, if I deleted these (white) atoms, the overall structure appears to be much cleaner and nicer as below.
[image: New structure: with atoms deleted manually]
[image: Legend]

Now with all these changes in the structure, I am seeing several band lines pass through the Fermi level in the optimized structure (shown in image 2).
[image: Band Structure]

Does this (lack of band-gap) occur because of the atoms deviating from the cubic diamond crystal arrangement? Is this acceptable to occur in a structure (since the original cross section was manually set by carving out a cylindrical region from a bulk block of Si)?
Or could it be some error caused by me during the calculation?

My fdf script is attached as well

```
SystemName       Si
SystemLabel      Si

NumberOfSpecies    1
NumberOfAtoms      185

%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
 1 14 Si
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel

LatticeConstant 5.41 Ang
%block LatticeVectors 
 10.00  0.00   0.00
  0.00  1.00   0.00
  0.00  0.00  10.00
%endblock LatticeVectors

AtomCoorFormatOut           Ang
AtomicCoordinatesFormat     Ang
%block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
20.2875000000000000 1.3525000000000000  14.8775000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 2.7050000000000000  13.5250000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 0.0000000000000000  13.5250000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 4.0575000000000000  14.8775000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 1.3525000000000000  14.8775000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 2.7050000000000000  13.5250000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 0.0000000000000000  13.5250000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 4.0575000000000000  14.8775000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 1.3525000000000000  14.8775000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 2.7050000000000000  13.5250000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 4.0575000000000000  14.8775000000000000 1
14.8775000000000000 1.3525000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
16.2300000000000000 2.7050000000000000  18.9350000000000000 1
18.9350000000000000 0.0000000000000000  18.9350000000000000 1
18.9350000000000000 2.7050000000000000  16.2300000000000000 1
17.5825000000000000 1.3525000000000000  17.5825000000000000 1
17.5825000000000000 4.0575000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
20.2875000000000000 1.3525000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
20.2875000000000000 4.0575000000000000  17.5825000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 0.0000000000000000  16.2300000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 2.7050000000000000  18.9350000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 0.0000000000000000  18.9350000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 2.7050000000000000  16.2300000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 1.3525000000000000  17.5825000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 4.0575000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 1.3525000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 4.0575000000000000  17.5825000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 0.0000000000000000  16.2300000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 2.7050000000000000  18.9350000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 0.0000000000000000  18.9350000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 2.7050000000000000  16.2300000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 1.3525000000000000  17.5825000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 4.0575000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 1.3525000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 4.0575000000000000  17.5825000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 0.0000000000000000  16.2300000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 2.7050000000000000  18.9350000000000000 1
35.1650000000000000 0.0000000000000000  18.9350000000000000 1
35.1650000000000000 2.7050000000000000  16.2300000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 1.3525000000000000  17.5825000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 4.0575000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
36.5175000000000000 1.3525000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
36.5175000000000000 4.0575000000000000  17.5825000000000000 1
37.8700000000000000 2.7050000000000000  18.9350000000000000 1
39.2225000000000000 4.0575000000000000  20.2875000000000000 1
13.5250000000000000 0.0000000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
13.5250000000000000 2.7050000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
14.8775000000000000 1.3525000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
14.8775000000000000 4.0575000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
16.2300000000000000 0.0000000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
16.2300000000000000 2.7050000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
18.9350000000000000 0.0000000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
18.9350000000000000 2.7050000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
17.5825000000000000 1.3525000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
17.5825000000000000 4.0575000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
20.2875000000000000 1.3525000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
20.2875000000000000 4.0575000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 0.0000000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 2.7050000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 0.0000000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 2.7050000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 1.3525000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 4.0575000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 1.3525000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 4.0575000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 0.0000000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 2.7050000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 0.0000000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 2.7050000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 1.3525000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 4.0575000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 1.3525000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 4.0575000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 0.0000000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 2.7050000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
35.1650000000000000 0.0000000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
35.1650000000000000 2.7050000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 1.3525000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 4.0575000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
36.5175000000000000 1.3525000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
36.5175000000000000 4.0575000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
37.8700000000000000 0.0000000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
37.8700000000000000 2.7050000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
40.5750000000000000 0.0000000000000000  24.3450000000000000 1
40.5750000000000000 2.7050000000000000  21.6400000000000000 1
39.2225000000000000 1.3525000000000000  22.9925000000000000 1
39.2225000000000000 4.0575000000000000  25.6975000000000000 1
13.5250000000000000 0.0000000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
13.5250000000000000 2.7050000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
14.8775000000000000 1.3525000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
14.8775000000000000 4.0575000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
16.2300000000000000 0.0000000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
16.2300000000000000 2.7050000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
18.9350000000000000 0.0000000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
18.9350000000000000 2.7050000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
17.5825000000000000 1.3525000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
17.5825000000000000 4.0575000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
20.2875000000000000 1.3525000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
20.2875000000000000 4.0575000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 0.0000000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 2.7050000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 0.0000000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 2.7050000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 1.3525000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 4.0575000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 1.3525000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 4.0575000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 0.0000000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 2.7050000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 0.0000000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 2.7050000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 1.3525000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 4.0575000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 1.3525000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 4.0575000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 0.0000000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 2.7050000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
35.1650000000000000 0.0000000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
35.1650000000000000 2.7050000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 1.3525000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 4.0575000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
36.5175000000000000 1.3525000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
36.5175000000000000 4.0575000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
37.8700000000000000 0.0000000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
37.8700000000000000 2.7050000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
40.5750000000000000 0.0000000000000000  29.7550000000000000 1
40.5750000000000000 2.7050000000000000  27.0500000000000000 1
39.2225000000000000 1.3525000000000000  28.4025000000000000 1
39.2225000000000000 4.0575000000000000  31.1075000000000000 1
13.5250000000000000 2.7050000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
14.8775000000000000 4.0575000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
16.2300000000000000 0.0000000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
16.2300000000000000 2.7050000000000000  35.1650000000000000 1
18.9350000000000000 0.0000000000000000  35.1650000000000000 1
18.9350000000000000 2.7050000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
17.5825000000000000 1.3525000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
17.5825000000000000 4.0575000000000000  36.5175000000000000 1
20.2875000000000000 1.3525000000000000  36.5175000000000000 1
20.2875000000000000 4.0575000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 0.0000000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 2.7050000000000000  35.1650000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 0.0000000000000000  35.1650000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 2.7050000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 1.3525000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 4.0575000000000000  36.5175000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 1.3525000000000000  36.5175000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 4.0575000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 0.0000000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 2.7050000000000000  35.1650000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 0.0000000000000000  35.1650000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 2.7050000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 1.3525000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 4.0575000000000000  36.5175000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 1.3525000000000000  36.5175000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 4.0575000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 0.0000000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 2.7050000000000000  35.1650000000000000 1
35.1650000000000000 0.0000000000000000  35.1650000000000000 1
35.1650000000000000 2.7050000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 1.3525000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 4.0575000000000000  36.5175000000000000 1
36.5175000000000000 1.3525000000000000  36.5175000000000000 1
36.5175000000000000 4.0575000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
37.8700000000000000 0.0000000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
37.8700000000000000 2.7050000000000000  35.1650000000000000 1
40.5750000000000000 2.7050000000000000  32.4600000000000000 1
39.2225000000000000 1.3525000000000000  33.8125000000000000 1
18.9350000000000000 2.7050000000000000  37.8700000000000000 1
20.2875000000000000 4.0575000000000000  39.2225000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 0.0000000000000000  37.8700000000000000 1
21.6400000000000000 2.7050000000000000  40.5750000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 0.0000000000000000  40.5750000000000000 1
24.3450000000000000 2.7050000000000000  37.8700000000000000 1
22.9925000000000000 1.3525000000000000  39.2225000000000000 1
25.6975000000000000 4.0575000000000000  39.2225000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 0.0000000000000000  37.8700000000000000 1
27.0500000000000000 2.7050000000000000  40.5750000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 0.0000000000000000  40.5750000000000000 1
29.7550000000000000 2.7050000000000000  37.8700000000000000 1
28.4025000000000000 1.3525000000000000  39.2225000000000000 1
31.1075000000000000 4.0575000000000000  39.2225000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 0.0000000000000000  37.8700000000000000 1
32.4600000000000000 2.7050000000000000  40.5750000000000000 1
35.1650000000000000 2.7050000000000000  37.8700000000000000 1
33.8125000000000000 1.3525000000000000  39.2225000000000000 1
%endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies

%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
  1  0  0  0.0
  0  6  0  0.0
  0  0  1  0.0
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack

PAO.BasisSize           DZP
XC.functional           LDA 
XC.authors              CA 
SpinPolarized           .false. 
MeshCutoff              150 Ry  
kgrid_cutoff            100.0 Ang

MD.TypeOfRun            CG 
MD.VariableCell         true 
MD.NumCGsteps           500 
MD.MaxCGDispl           0.1 Bohr 
MD.MaxForceTol          0.04 eV/Ang  
MD.MaxStressTol         0.0001 eV/Ang**3 

MD.UseSaveCG            true
MD.UseSaveXV            true
MaxSCFIterations        500
DM.MixingWeight         0.01
DM.NumberPulay          3
DM.Tolerance            1.d-3
#ElectronicTemperature   25 meV
SolutionMethod          diagon

BandLinesScale ReciprocalLatticeVectors
%block BandLines
1   0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 \Gamma
100 0.0000000000 0.5000000000 0.0000000000 y
%endblock BandLines

%block WaveFuncKPoints
0.000 0.000 0.000 from 1 to 100
%endblock WaveFuncKPoints
```

Comment: Two comments, your `dm.tolerance` is rather high and your `meshcutoff` is rather low. I would ensure these are converged with respect to this system before concluding too much.

Comment: @zeroth thanks for the comment. I shall start working on that as well.

Comment: Briefly speaking, what you observe during the geometry optimization is the surface restructuring of the Si surface, and the vanishing band gap is due to surface states. Do you really want to calculate a Si nanowire with a clean surface? Real-world Si surfaces are seldom clean, but are usually either terminated by hydrogen atoms or by hydroxyl groups. I don't know if the surfaces of Si nanowires are generally clean, but I guess this is not the case.

Comment: @wzkchem5 thanks for the reply. The thing is I am studying the thermal transport in pristine Si nanowires using molecular dynamics simulations. This is why I did not try to terminate the surface using 'H' or 'OH' groups. Now that this problem has risen, I think that it is best to terminate the surface as mentioned. Also, is there a way to define these terminations? I know that Avogadro can do this, but the final structure usually consists of excess H atoms.

Comment: Are you aware that DFT is not an adequate method for computing bands?

Comment: @CarlosAndrésdelValle what do you mean by that? I am aware that DFT cannot produce the accurate band gap of a material and so on. However when experimental investigations are not feasible, how exactly does one compare (band structure and other electronic properties) several nanostructures with one another? Are you saying that there are alternate and significantly more accurate methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that after taking into consideration what the comments have pointed out you should also look into the fact that as your geometry has changed somewhat considerably after the optimization. This change in geometry would cause a breaking in the symmetry and thus when the BS is being calculated, as you go through your Brillouin zone you are not going to "see" the same states you saw before. Have you looked into this ? Hope this makes sense.

Here is reference on what I am trying to convey:

G. Vasseur, et al. Effect of Symmetry Breaking on Electronic Band Structure: Gap Opening at the High Symmetry Points *Symmetry* **2013**, 5(4), 344-354; https://doi.org/10.3390/sym5040344

Comment: No I have not looked into this. I decided to look at structures with `H` terminations to remove the surface states and managed to get a decent band structure.